# loading log4j.xml using maven test

Tags: java, maven, junit, log4j

I am trying to run 'mvn test' with my java code loading 'log4j.xml'. I am getting file not found exception. Would be great to get some help.

**My java code:**

```
public class MyClass {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    public boolean check(){
        try{
            DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
            logger.info("into the method");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Junit test case:**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyClassTests {

    @Test
    public void testCheck() {
        MyClass myc = new MyClass();
        assertEquals(true, myc.check()); 
    }
}
```

**block of pom.xml**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                <include>log4j.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
        </configuration>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
    </plugin>
```

File Structure:

- pom.xml = */myproject/pom.xml
- log4j.xml = */myproject/src/main/resources/log4j.xml
- myclass.java = */myproject/src/main/java/MyClass.java
- junit test = */myproject/src/test/java/MyClassTests.java

When I run the command "mvn test", I get a file not found exception for log4j.xml:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   */myproject/log4j.xml (No such file or
>   directory)

Basically the code is looking for log4j.xml in the root folder of the project rather than in the /src/main/resources folder. I do not want to change the code to "DOMConfigurator.configure("/src/main/resources/log4j.xml");" This will cause issue in the deployed application. Need a more elegant solution.

Comment: The below code resolved the issue. This question can be closed:
           'DOMConfigurator.configure(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("log4j.xml"));'

Comment: That works but also because log4j.xml is read relative to a resource root, then it should DomConfigurator.configurator("/log4j.xml") should also work if log4j.xml is in src/main/resources.   DomConfigurator.configurator("log4j.xml") will try to load from the same package that myClass resides.   This is how URL classloaders resolve classes/resources.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see your POM but you should have a resources section in your build declaration to ensure the src/main/resources are available as a class resource.

```
    <build>
    <outputDirectory>build/maven/${artifactId}/target/classes</outputDirectory>

<resources>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

Then the DOMConfigurator should be able to locate the log4j.xml as a class resource.  If you run a maven package on your project you should look in the build or target folder and see that the log4j.xml is copied to the classes folder. Then you'll know it should be available as a resource.

Comment: The log4j.xml is getting copied to the target/classes folder even now. Will try your approach though. I was wondering whether I can load the DOM configuration from an input stream rather than giving the file name. I am loading my config file that way. It is working fine 'InputStream config = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");' My config file is in the same directory as the log4j.xml file.

Comment: The solution proposed by you did not work. I was getting the same message. However I was able to make it work using class loader. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Tried the same and it didn't work for me. Also note for log4j2 they want the file to be named log4j-test.xml for automatic configuration. I was trying with log4j-test.xml.

Comment: That works but also because log4j.xml is read relative to a resource root, then it should DomConfigurator.configurator("/log4j.xml") should also work if log4j.xml is in src/main/resources. DomConfigurator.configurator("log4j.xml") will try to load from the same package that myClass resides. This is how URL classloaders resolve classes/resources.